# Prevent pdflatex.ini repair when updating packages in miktex

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I've installed Miktex for the local user only so it is installed in `C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9`. I had to add `save_size=80000` to `pdflatex.ini` in `..\miktex\config` to avoid errors when compiling a large document.

However, each time I update packages with the package manager the `pdflatex.ini` is repaired to its original. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run on the command line

```
 initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex
```

This will open a local pdflatex.ini in which you can put your save-size setting